# Observing the sequence of I, P and B frames

Tags: codec, encoder

I am using an X264 encoder. How can I possibly see the sequence of I, P, B frames how they are being encoded while encoding I mentioned these parameters

likely 
**x264 --crf 23 --tune fastdecode --fps 64 --keyint 1 --min-keyint 1 --no-scenecut --input-res 4096*2048 --bframes 3  -o filename**

Is it possible to see these sequences while decoding (using ijkplayer)?

Answer (score -1):

Add additional parameter "--log-level debug" for x264 encoder, and you will see encode order and picture order(POC).

An example of output is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTiMS.png

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It's working. can you please tell me what SKIP and NAL signifies?

Comment: can u please tell me what set of commands or parameter settings u used to generate the result you have given as a snapshot?

Comment: SKIP means the count of skip MB. NAL means nal priority,

Comment: SKIP means the count of skip MB(https://www.vcodex.com/news/skip-macroblocks/), the more skip MB the lesser nal size. NAL means nal priority, for example I slice have NAL=3, P have NAL=2, B slice which will be ref by other slice have NAL=2 and B slice which no other slice will ref have NAL=0. As snapshot command, i use default paramter, but add "--log-level debug"  to display some debug information.

Comment: so if I make NAL value for P frames = 0, does it mean all P frames will only be referenced to I frames (using the i_nal_ref_idc parameter for P frames)? (consider no B frame is there)

Comment: NAL for P frame can't be 0. Only B frame which won't be referenced by other frames equal to 0.